# How to wait for Qtcpsocket data without freezing the GUI in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtcpsocket

I have implemented a **QTcpserver ** . After succesfull connection with the client( PLC), both exchange data in a 2 way hand shake. Means Server sends the data with a counter value and client will reply with the same value, the moment server receives the value it send with incremented counter value. This goes on in a loop. I have done using signals and slot.
`connect(m_tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(socketReadyRead()));`
In the slot of socketReadyRead(), I am emitting the signal to data sending slot `connect(this,SIGNAL(newRawData()),this,SLOT(sendRawData()));` where I send new data with incremented counter value.Note that sendRawData() is called almost every 30ms.

```
    void TCPCommunicationPort::socketReadyRead()
    {
        emit newRawData();//connect to another slot where i send data
        //    qDebug()<<"bytes available "<<m_tcpSocket->bytesAvailable();
        QByteArray receivedData = m_tcpSocket->readAll();
        //I am updating the GUI written in QML through signals  
        emit sendDatatoQml(byteIndex,-1,overrideValue);
        //....
    }
```

Now, I send 48Bytes of data and I receive **68 bytes **of data from the client. To perform a function called Homing. I need to set/enable particlular bits in 48Bytes of sendData(say bits 1 and 2 of  6th byte ) and wait till particular bit in 68 bytes (Recevied data)(say 3rd bit of 10th byte) is true(this will be after few seconds) and then I have disable the bits 1 and 2 of  6th byte. Meanwhile the server has to keep on sending **48 bytes** of data with incremented counter value, otherwise it will disconnect. How to perfome this waiting ? Note that already data is exchanging in a loop.

I tried like this but Qt creator and app both freezed and crashed because of infinet while loop(uncommented it).If I remove while loop it is not entering into the If statement.I must wait at that If statement.

```
    void TCPCommunicationPort::startHoming()
    {
        if(!(m_senddataBuffer[CREG1] & (1 << EMSTOP)))
          {
            m_senddataBuffer[CREG1] |= 1<<EMSTOP;
            bool bitvalue = (m_senddataBuffer[CREG1] & (1 << EMSTOP));
            dataFromCppUpdate(CREG1,EMSTOP,bitvalue);
          }
        if(!(m_senddataBuffer[CREG1] & (1 << MSTOP)))
          {
            m_senddataBuffer[CREG1] |= 1<<MSTOP;
            bool bitvalue = (m_senddataBuffer[CREG1] & (1 << MSTOP));
            dataFromCppUpdate(CREG1,MSTOP,bitvalue);
          }
          //    emit newRawData();
          bool enter =true;
         if(m_tcpSocket->waitForReadyRead())
            {
            qDebug()<<"I am waiting for ACK...";

             if((m_oldData[SREG1] & (1 << ACKSTART)))//how should I wait here till that bit is enabled?
                {
                 qDebug()<<"Ack received please disable the Bit";
                }
            }
    qDebug()<<"homing is done";
    }
```

Once again,I am getting data from client almost every 30ms and I am reading it to receivedData[] . That means connect(m_tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(socketReadyRead())); socketReadyRead() is called every 30ms. So my IF statement works.But I must wait till one of the Bit in 68Bytes(say 3rd bit of 10th byte ) of data i receive from client is enabled.It keeps on sending 68 bytes of data(every 30ms) but after some time when the work is done it will send me an Ack(Almost after 10Sec not ms) by enabling the 3rd bit(ACKSTART) of 10th byte(SREG1).`if((m_oldData[SREG1] & (1 << ACKSTART)))//how should I wait here till this bit is enabled?`
Can anyone please tell me the logic to wait without freezing the GUI. Do I need to put this function startHoming in separate Qthread? If so how to do that? Please provide me an example. Thanks a lot

Comment: run the function in a thread

Comment: Don't listen to people who say "run xxx in a thread". Simply forget that the `waitForXxx` methods exist. Ignore them. Once you do, you'll know what to do :)

Comment: @KubaOber As you said if (m_tcpSocket->waitForReadyRead()) is doing my purpose. May i know why my qDebug()<<"got the message..." statement is never called.
Edit: I have updated the quesiton and removed while loop.

Comment: The `readyRead` signal indicates that you've got at least one new byte of data. It doesn't mean anything else. All that you can expect after `waitForReadyRead` is that there is *one* more byte of available data, *or* that the connection has timed out. I see nothing in your code that checks for how much data is available. The code with `wait` is not using `read` or `readAll` anyway.

Comment: You're also assuming that `waitForReadyRead` will allow signals to be emitted. That may or may not be the case. Since it's not documented, you can't depend on it. Again, `waitForXxx` are *way more trouble than they are worth* and unless you read **and understand** Qt source code, you can't use them. They simply aren't sufficiently documented to be useful, and most of their uses in SO questions assume a whole lot of fantasies that aren't backed up by documentation, and usually aren't how Qt acts either. Basically, `waitForXxx` are for pros, who know better than to use them anyway.

Comment: @Kuba Ober and even if you know what you are doing and you are using them, they are bugged as ****

Comment: @KubaOber I have update the question. The question is simple I just need to wait at the IF statement.Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You don't need to wait. Instead of waiting, let your code be called when there's data. You're not inconveniencing us, you're inconveniencing yourself :)